# If one record does not exist select another

Tags: mysql, sql

I've build an Multi Language app. The database looks like:

**Table things**

```
|id| img |url|
--------------
|1 |     |   |
|2 |     |   |
|3 |     |   |
```

**Table things_translations**

```
|id|  thing_id | title | locale |
---------------------------------
|1 |     1     |       |    en  |
|2 |     2     |       |    en  |
|3 |     3     |       |    en  |
|4 |     2     |       |    ru  |
```

I have the default language to English (locale=en).

When I get the translations `title` from `things_translations` in other language than English and this language does not exist yet in the database I would like to get the english version of it.

I've tried the below query but returns all records instead:

```
select things.id 
FROM things 
INNER JOIN things_translations ON things.id = things_translations.thing_id 
WHERE CASE WHEN things_translations.locale = ru IS NULL 
THEN things_translations.locale = en END
```

With the above query I get both language for `thing_id:2` but I only want to get the `ru locale` not the `en` because exist.

Comment: Can you also add the expected result?

Comment: Why don't you try OR condition ? rather than case things_translations.locale = ru or things_translations.locale = en

Comment: @jarlh I want to get only one locale each time for each thing not all.

Comment: @Gopidoss the or will return all locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(TT1.title,TT.title)
FROM things T
LEFT JOIN things_translations TT 
    ON (T.id = TT.thing_id AND TT.locale = 'en')
LEFT JOIN things_translations TT1 
    ON (T.id = TT1.thing_id AND TT1.locale = 'ru')
WHERE T.id = 2;
```

> [SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3385a7/2)

Answer (score 1):

I've working on same type of application and solve my problem with CASE :

```
SELECT t.id FROM things t 
INNER JOIN things_translations tt ON t.id = tt.thing_id 
AND tt.locale = CASE WHEN 
EXISTS(SELECT tte.locale FROM things_translations tte WHERE tt.thing_id = t.id AND tte.locale = 'ru') THEN 'ru' 
    ELSE 'en'
    END
```

Comment: It returns Unknown column 'ru' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did it with @zakhefron answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CASE` is evaluating to true, hence showing everything.

You could join things_translations twice--once with your selected language, and once with english, in the respective clauses.  Then your column would be `COALESCE(things_translations.title, things_translations_en.title)`.  In other words, try things_translations (your selected-language join) for title, and if that's null, use the title from things_translations_en.  You'll also need in your where clause something making the two joins' IDs equal, otherwise you'll get too many rows.